# email doesnt send in mvc but works in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, email-confirmation

I have switched to ASP.NET MVC recently. I want to send email confirmation when people sign up to my website.

So I uncomment the code that ASP.NET MVC has by default for this and add configuration in `web.config` but that doesn't work and I kept having this error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

I created an asp.net webforms and tried to send email from that project and that worked. So I copied the code that I had in my page load for sending email in webforms and put it in register action in account controller but I had that error again.

I really can't understand why I get this error in ASP.NET MVC, but the exact same code works fine in webforms.

This is the code in ASP.NET MVC register action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, BirthDate=model.BirthDate };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                //string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                //await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                //create the mail message 
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                //set the addresses 
                mail.From = new MailAddress("info@wwwebco.com"); //IMPORTANT: This must be same as your smtp authentication address.
                mail.To.Add(user.Id);

                //set the content 
                mail.Subject = "This is an email";
                mail.Body = "This is from system.net.mail using C sharp with smtp authentication.";
                //send the message 
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.wwwebco.com");

                //IMPORANT:  Your smtp login email MUST be same as your FROM address. 
                NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@wwwebco.com", "MyPassWord");
                smtp.Credentials = Credentials;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and the code that I had in the asp.net webforms app and works fine is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create the mail message 
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    //set the addresses 
    mail.From = new MailAddress("info@wwwebco.com"); //IMPORTANT: This must be same as your smtp authentication address.
    mail.To.Add("armanhafezi@gmail.com");

    //set the content 
    mail.Subject = "This is an email";
    mail.Body = "This is from system.net.mail using C sharp with smtp authentication.";
    //send the message 
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.wwwebco.com");

    //IMPORANT:  Your smtp login email MUST be same as your FROM address. 
    NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@wwwebco.com", "MyPassWord");
    smtp.Credentials = Credentials;
    smtp.Send(mail); 

}
```

I am really stuck with this problem. Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the port number your SMTP server requires?

Comment: yes i had tried that. i have that in web.config configuration now. my port is 25.

Comment: On a side note, I hope that's not your real password in the second example you pasted there...

Comment: use a strong password for the senders mail..

Comment: Is this error happening on your local development machine or when deployed?

Comment: @jeroenh thank you man, that was mistake.

Comment: @sarath i didnt have a strong password first, then i changed my password with a strong one but still doesnt work.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen i didnt try thease codes local. i upload on server. because i dont know how to examin email on local host.

Comment: Can you run it, with a breakpoint on `smtp.Credentials = Credentials;` and see what happens. If you are doing a lot of work with email, you can always try Mail4Net, which allows you to unit test your email sending. Of course, this wouldn't help with the credentials issue!

Comment: @KarlGjertsen thank you for your information. anyway i khnow the code is right and i know the server sends email (it works in asp.net webform). but i dont know the problem with MVC.

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to see what happens?

Comment: Can you add the MVC code? The code you have posted is ASP.NET.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen i added breakpoint and i got no error. my smtp reads my username and password and host. but the odd thing is smtp shows my massage is empty. is it norm?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen the first code is mvc code. i coppied that from my account controller. its my register action.

Comment: When debugging, the `mail` object should show the properties.

Comment: If you want to try your codes locally, you can use [smtp4dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) which will simulate a fake smtp server

Comment: @KarlGjertsen i saw my smtp.credential in breakpoint and my username was "armanhafezi@hotmail.com" but this mail is the mail that i want to be sent not my username. my credential object shows my real username. do you know whay this happend??!!

Comment: What is the value of `user.Id`?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen armanhafezi@hotmail.com

Comment: If the credentials are showing correctly, were you viewing the wrong object?

Comment: i see a credential object wich shows correct, and i have a smtp.credential property that shows the wrong username.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have you tried changing the `user.Id` to a hard coded email address?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen thak you for update. i checked my web.cong and my username was inccorect there in my visualstudio. but i checked the server and i had fixed that in server's textEditor. i fixed web.config and now it shows correct username. but i saw my mail object, everything is ok but my sender is null. can this make problem?

Comment: Yes! That would be the problem. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Why are you using `user.Id` and not `model.Email`?

If you have any blank or missing details, this can cause an error?

**Original:**

You should change the `mail.From` to be `mail.Sender`.

Are you loading the ASP.NET Web Forms and the MVC to the same host environment?
Could one be blocking port 25, or requiring SMTP to be sent over HTTPS?

For HTTPS you would need to change your port number, usually port 465, but might be different, depending on your mail sender.

If your SMTP server has restrictions, try using [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com), which has a free account.

Comment: actually when i saw i couldnt send email from MVC i built a subdomain and run the webform website on that. but i had the problem before webform comes into play.

Comment: So does the error still happen when the MVC app is deployed to the sub-domain?

Comment: and my server doesnt support HTTPS and the told me always use port 25 for sending mail from server. and i am in iran and cant use many of the providers becuase i recieved TIME/ZONE error.

Comment: why my sender is null? have i missed something?

Comment: You have set the From Address, not the Sender Address! See the MailMessage class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes man you really helped me. i cant upvote your answer becuase it seems i need more reputation or something. but if u come to my country i will buy you a coffee. :-)

Comment: That's what you're supposed to do! :-)